# Is there a one-line initialization for C structs on the heap?

Tags: c

In C, we can initialize a `struct` on the stack in the following way.

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    int bar2;
};


int main(){
    struct Foo myFoo = {
        .bar = 1,
        .bar2 = 2
    };
}
```

However, when, I try this kind of thing the `heap`, the compiler refused it.

```
struct Foo* myFooPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
*myFooPtr = {
    .bar = 1,
    .bar2 = 2
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     *myFooPtr = {
```

Is there a way to achieve kind of initialization on the heap?

Comment: you can use `memset()` to initialise the memory, or `memcopy()` for some cases.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here: `.bar` and `.bar2` aren't necessary, all you need is just `{ 1, 2 }`, both here, and in the answer.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin, That appears to also work for the top case, although it is arguably more clear to do explicit assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
struct Foo *myFooPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
*myFooPtr = (struct Foo) {
        .bar = 1,
        .bar2 = 2
    };
```

(although formally this an initialisation of an anonymous compound literal object followed by an *assignment* to the heap object, rather than a direct initialisation).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize dynamically allocated objects. They have to be assigned rather than initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int main()
{
   struct Foo *myFooPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
   struct Foo myFoo = { 1, 2 };
   *myFooPtr = (struct Foo) { 5, 8 };
}
```

That should work too.

Comment: Why did you declare myFoo?